# How can I return the updated object that is inside an array?

Tags: mongodb

I currently have this data structure:

db.mydatabase:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee50f412312e02d446aee2"),
        "descripcion" : "filtros de aceite",
        "array_repuesto" : [ 
            {                    --> I need this object!
                "referencia" : "referencia3",  
                "marca" : "adidas2",
                "precio" : 900012
            }, 
            {
                "referencia" : "referencia2",
                "marca" : "nike",
                "precio" : 8000
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee50f40a2323d446aee2"),
        "descripcion" : "filtros de agua",
        "array_repuesto" : [ 
            {
                "referencia" : "referencia5",
                "marca" : "adidas2",
                "precio" : 900012
            }, 
            {
                "referencia" : "referencia7",
                "marca" : "nike",
                "precio" : 8000
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ee50f40a752be023232"),
        "descripcion" : "filtros de arroz",
        "array_repuesto" : [ 

        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

I'm filtering the object where `referencia = 'referencia3'`, but I don't know how to make it only return the updated

```
db.mydatabase.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
    _id: body._id, 
    "array_repuesto.referencia": "referencia3",
    },
    {
    $set: 
    { 
        'array_repuesto.$.marca': 'SOS',
        'array_repuesto.$.precio': '0',
       },
    },

    (err, repuestoDb) => {
     .
     .
     .
```

Output desired:

```
            {
                "referencia" : "referencia3",
                "marca" : "adidas2",
                "precio" : 900012
            },
```

how can I do it? (by the way, is there a way to get the object back to me before updating?)